# Returning dynamic key value collection in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, keyvaluepair, namevaluecollection

I am developing an ASP.Net Web API project. In my project, I am trying to return JSON from action in this format.

```
{
  "Apple": null,
  "Microsoft": null,
  "Google": 'http://placehold.it/250x250'
}
```

As you can see in the JSON, it is key value pairs. Both key and value are dynamic. So I tried to return `NameValueCollection` from action to get that format. Here is my code:

```
public class CompaniesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        NameValueCollection collection = new NameValueCollection();
        collection.Add("Microsoft", "microsoft.com");
        collection.Add("Google", "google.com");
        collection.Add("Facebook", "facebook.com");
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, collection, "application/json");
    }
}
```

But then I access the action, it is returning the JSON like below.

[image]

As you can see, it is only returning Keys. Names are excluded. That is not the format I want. How can I fix my code to get name value pairs returned?

Comment: Use `Dictionary<string,object>`

Comment: Thanks so much. it worked with Dictionary. Will you post answer? I want to upvote the answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `Dictionary<string, object>` to add key value pairs.

```
public class CompaniesController : ApiController {
    // GET api/<controller>
    public HttpResponseMessage Get() {
        var collection = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        collection.Add("Microsoft", "microsoft.com");
        collection.Add("Google", "google.com");
        collection.Add("Facebook", "facebook.com");
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, collection, "application/json");
    }
}
```

with `application/json`, the above will return

```js
{
  "Microsoft": "microsoft.com",
  "Google": "google.com",
  "Facebook": "facebook.com"
}
```

Comment: hi how can I set result as json object with custom key
`"result" 
{
  "Microsoft": "microsoft.com",
  "Google": "google.com",
  "Facebook": "facebook.com"
}`

Comment: @Neo create a new anonymous object with result as property name. Using example above you would return `new { result = collection }`

Comment: @Neo I added it as an answer to your last posted question.